# What is the importance of Associated primes of a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

What is the importance of Associated primes of a ring? Does it have many applications in commutative algebra or other fields?

I am interested in applications of Associated primes and its links to other topics in Algebra.

Many Thanks

Comment: I know its link with zero divisors in Noetherian case.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, they provide a refinement of the theory of primary decomposition. Since they are contained in the support of the module, you can localize the module at them and not get a zero module.

I think associated primes are also used to study uniform modules over Noetherian rings.

It also shows up again when defining *unmixedness* of an ideal in Noetherian rings.

Comment: thank you very much.  the question is about Associated primes of a *ring* not a module, but what is the link between associated primes and uniform modules ?

Comment: @13571 the associated primes are ideals of the ring either way, there is no difference. I don’t know what the link with uniform modules is, if there is one.  Why’d you ask?

Comment: u said: "I think associated primes are also used to study uniform modules over Noetherian rings."

Comment: @13571 hrm, I have forgotten how I made that connection... this strikes me as the sort of thawing that would be in goodearl and warfields book on Noetherian rings.