What is the importance of Jacobson radical of a ring?
There are many questions here, in this site, about Jacobson radical of a ring. Also, it is defined in  algebra books that I saw.
What is the importance of Jacobson radical of a ring, so that one would study the topic and know it? Does it have many applications in commutative algebra?
I am also interested in applications of Jacobson radical and its links to other topics in Algebra.
Many Thanks

Update: This question is different from those who linked as "duplicate note".

similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3405370/what-is-the-importance-of-associated-primes-of-a-ring

I can't say that I have a full answer to your question, but the Jacobson radical makes an appearance in some of the most important theorems of commutative algebra, such as Nakayama's lemma (at least, in some versions of Nakayama's lemma). By the way, a lot of tools in commutative algebra originated from algebraic geometry. Perhaps reading a book such as this would shed some light.

What is the importance? (opinion based) Does it have many applications? (What does it mean to "apply a subset of a ring"?  or "obviously yes", take your pick). This question might be a good one to use to collect links to relevant questions that contain pertinent discussions (like the ones alluded to in the original post.)

If I were to try to summarize it in any way it'd be "it is a useful entity in the study of the structure of modules and rings," but that is not really the whole story.

Thank You very much @Joe

Thank You very much @rschwieb

the whole story @rschwieb

@user1401 None of your edits have addressed the issues with the post. Setting aside "opinion based," there is still the issue about it being "self-evident" because "There are many questions here, in this site, [...] Also, it is defined in algebra books". Information on the importance and "application," (whatever it is) is in all the text you can't be bothered to read.  It isn't clear what the use of this question would be beyond linking to already existing information.
